# the text overflows horizontally but should had overflowed vertically

Tags: html, css

My text in HTML goes vertically horizontally

[should have been like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd0OX.png)

[it went like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Kfn.png)

THIS one above is my code written in text
[This one  is his](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO2OW.png)

```
    `
<html> 
    <head>
        <style>
            #box{
                width: 250px;
                height: 250px;
                border: 2px solid black;   
               
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>CSS overflow</h1>

        <div id="box">
            aldskf;jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdaslk;jlaksjdfaslkdjfaslkjlkjlkjkljlk;;sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfjkaldslgrjlgfjlkgjslkjfsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddglkjgrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrra;oi      
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use realistic text in your test code (i.e. text with words and spaces between them), then your problem will disappear...

Answer (score 1):

Because his example is seperating the words, they will automatically break to a new line when it needs to, since you just have a string of characters you will need to tell the css to break automatically

Add `overflow-wrap: break-word` to your css [here's what it looks like for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvuaV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `word-wrap: break-word`

```
#box{
   word-wrap: break-word
 }
```